# When keep me logged in is checked it is not displaying the user data

Tags: php

I was making a simple Login script that should keep the user logged in when the radio-button is checked. 
I have set a cookie to expire after 24 hours if the "Keep me logged in" radio-button is checked, and it worked... 
But i get some errors that say: **Notice: Undefined index: user_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Webintegrator-PHP\MySql&PHP\Register&Login\core_login.php on line 17**
 & **Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Webintegrator-PHP\MySql&PHP\Register&Login\core_login.php on line 20**

These are the users firstname and surname which should be displayed from the database..

But they are always displayed when the user log in until the radio-button "Keep me logged in" is checked.

Here is the code for **login_form.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $password_hash = md5($password);

    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
        $query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "' AND password = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($password_hash) . "'";
        if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
            $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);

            if($query_num_rows == 0) {
                echo "Invalid username/password combination";
            } elseif ($query_num_rows == 1) {

                if(isset($_POST['remember_me'])){
                    setcookie("remember_username", $_POST['username'], time()+3600*24);
                    setcookie("remember_password", $_POST['password'], time()+3600*24);

                    $user_id = mysql_result($query_run, 0, 'id');
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

                    header ('Location: index_login.php');

                } elseif(isset($_POST['keep_me'])){
                    $user_id = mysql_result($query_run, 0, 'id');
                    setcookie('keep_me_loggedin', $user_id, time()+3600*24);

                    header ('Location: index_login.php');

                } else {
                    $user_id = mysql_result($query_run, 0, 'id');
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

                    header ('Location: index_login.php');                    
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "You must supply a username & password";
    }
}

?>

<form action="<?php echo $current_file; ?>" method="POST">
    Username:<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['remember_username'])) {echo $_COOKIE['remember_username'];} ?>"><br/><br/>
    Password:<input type="password" name="password" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['remember_password'])) {echo $_COOKIE['remember_password'];} ?>"><br/><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="remember_me"> Remember me?<br/><br/> 
    <input type="radio" name="keep_me"> Keep me logged in?<br/><br/> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

And **index_login.php**

```
<?php

require 'connect_login.php';
require 'core_login.php';

if(loggedin()) {
    $firstname = getuserfield('firstname');
    $surname = getuserfield('surname');
    echo "You are logged in, " . "$firstname " . "$surname " . "<a href='logout.php'>Log out</a>";
} else {
    include 'login_form.php';
}

?>
```

And here is **core_login.php**

```
<?php

ob_start();
session_start();

$current_file = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

function loggedin(){
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id']) || (isset($_COOKIE['keep_me_loggedin'])) && (!empty($_COOKIE['keep_me_loggedin']))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function getuserfield($field) {
    $query = "SELECT $field FROM users WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";

    if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
        return mysql_result($query_run, 0, $field);
    }    
}


?>
```

Any solutions for the problem would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need to do some additional condition-checking.

Check that $query_run is a valid mysql query result.

And you want to check that isset($_SESSION['user_id']) is true before trying to stick it in the query in getuserfield().

EDIT:

I found this on the PHP mysql_query() page:

```
The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(), and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the returned data.
```

That means you should use mysql_fetch_array() rather than mysql_result() to access the results of the executed query.

[PHP - mysql_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: the $query_run is working.. as i said i can login & logout with $_SESSION['user_id']. But when the user check the radio button "keep me logged in" then i want the user to be logged in with a cookie.. So that the next time the user visit the page he should still be logged in. But the problem is that when the user is logged in with a cookie then it it not displaying the user firstname & surname

Comment: Oh it's probably because you don't set `$_SESSION['user_id']` in that elseif statement, but you set it in the other two.

You should just have one `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id` statement, instead of 3 though. I would place it right before checking for $_POST['remember_me']`

Comment: As I said, you should check isset($_SESSION['user_id']) before trying to access it. The reason it works when you login/logout because you set the $_SESSION['user_id'] for those cases... But you didn't set it for the "keep me logged in" case.

Comment: You also may want to revise the logic for your loggedin() routine. In particular changing the || to &&.

Comment: Okay now i have set the `$_SESSION['user_id']` to work in all three cases.. Now when i login and check the radio button "keep me logged in" it display the user data, but when i close the browser and go to the **index_login.php** page then it show the same error with undefined index and it is not showing the user data again.. That means the cookie is not working as it should?

Comment: How could i store the firstname and the surname to the user from the database in a cookie when the user login?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325497/how-to-keep-the-session-active-even-if-the-browser-was-accidentally-close

Comment: I can't find a solution, could you please help me with the script.. I'm still new to Php

Comment: You should start a new question